# Let $H\unlhd G$ and $a\in G$. If the coset $aH$ has order $3$ in $G/H$ and $|H| = 10$, what are the possible $|a|$ in $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

### Context

I am an undergrad student taking Abstract Algebra I, and this is a problem on a homework assignment.

### Problem

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, and let $a ∈ G$. If the coset $aH$ has order 3 in
the factor group $G/H$, and $|H| = 10$, what are the possible orders of $a$ in $G$?

### What I know

- Since $H$ is a normal subgroup, its left coset should equal its right coset.
- Since $H$ has 10 elements, the highest order of an element should be 10.

Comment: Do you know what it means for a coset to have order 3 in the factor group?

Comment: Hint: the fact that $aH$ has order $3$ means that $a \not\in H$ but $a^3 \in H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the order of the coset $aH$ in the quotient group $G/H$ is the least positive integer $n$ such that $(aH)^n=H$, being $H$ the identity of $G/H$. But, by normality of $H$ in $G$, it is $(aH)^n=a^nH$ (induction on $n$), so $a^nH=H$ or, equivalently, $a^n\in H$. So, in your case, $a^3\in H$ and $a,a^2\notin H$. Now, $e=(a^3)^{|a^3|}=a^{3|a^3|}$, and hence $|a|$ divides $3|a^3|$. Since $|a^3|$ divides $|H|=10$, $|a^3|$ can be any among $1,2,5,10$, whence $3|a^3|$ can be any among $3,6,15,30$. To sum up, $|a|$ can be any among $3,5,6,10,15,30$, being $1$ and $2$ ruled out by the conditions $a,a^2\notin H$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

The order of $a^3$ is a divisor of the order of $H$ (Lagrange's theorem). On the other hand, if the order of $a$ is $d$, the order of $a^3$ is $\dfrac d{\gcd(d,3)}$. Can you deduce the possibilities for $d$?